# How to use Match, on example of reformating a phone number. (Capturing RegEx groups in dart.)

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a RegExp

```
RegExp(r'^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})');
```

And I want to format this : `1234567890` to this : `(123) 456-7890`

Please Note:
Originally it was another question. ([How to split a string on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191872/how-to-split-a-string-on-range/62193625#62193625))
But the author edited it, and I wanted to save the original meaning and the question. I hope It could be useful, for beginners in programming, especially learners of dart.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing groups are a way to treat multiple characters as a single unit.

```
var value1 = "1234567890000";
var value2 = "123";
var value3 = "";

List<String> formatPhoneNumber(String value) {
  var regExp = RegExp(r'^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})');
  var matches = regExp.firstMatch(value);

  var ver1 = '(${matches.group(1)}) ${matches.group(2)}-${matches.group(3)}';
  var ver2 = '';
  if (matches.group(1).isNotEmpty) {
    ver2 += '(${matches.group(1)})';
  }
  if (matches.group(2).isNotEmpty) {
    ver2 += ' ${matches.group(2)}';
  }
  if (matches.group(3).isNotEmpty) {
    ver2 += '-${matches.group(3)}';
  }
  return ['ver1: $ver1', 'ver2: $ver2'];
}


print(formatPhoneNumber(value1)); //[ver1: (123) 456-7890, ver2: (123) 456-7890]
print(formatPhoneNumber(value2)); //[ver1: (123) -, ver2: (123)]
print(formatPhoneNumber(value3)); //[ver1: (123) -, ver2: (123)]
```

If you need an input mask for a telephone numbers, use package: https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter